# What does it mean to have equal tail in confidence interval and small standard error in weighted logistic regression in stata

Tags: logistic, confidence-interval, standard-error

I am running a survey-weighted analysis of disease prevalence.

I set my survey analysis:

```
svyset cluster [pw=w_final]
```

All results are fine, except when I tried to run a logistic regression analysis to find the disease prevalence association with the area. My data is associated with the location so I did collect the data from 3 different localities which are in turn divided into 35 villages and I want to know if the location is associated with disease prevalence in localities and villages.

I used:

```
 svy: logistic goldstage1 i.locality
 svy: logistic goldstage1 i.village
```

and got weird results

OR(2.162456   **Std.Err 8.74e-12**  t 1.9e+11  P-value 0.000   CI(**2.162456-2.162456)**)

What does that mean? Just to mention that there are 1830 observations in my sample while I have very small numbers in the `goldstage1` variable.

Comment: For some reason your standard error for the odds ratio is very small and so the associated 95% confidence interval very narrow (not of zero width; that appearance is just a side-effect of display format). On whether that is really puzzling we can't tell without a view of your data. Nor is it clear how much difference the `svy` setting makes. As a good answer here may depend on knowing what Stata does given `svyset` and also on your data I think you would be better off asking on Statalist.  What does "very small numbers" mean for `goldstage1`? (that you have mostly zeros?).

Comment: I am assuming that I am having this results because of weighting problem! but I might be mistaken. 
Regarding the small numbers of goldstage1, this is an outcome variable and it's either 0 or 1! but what I mean is a small number of patients have 1 as an outcome results and the majority are zeros. For example, in one locality there are 17 with goldstage1=(1) and 507 with goldstage1=(0).

I am not sure how to show you my data here?

Comment: Statalist has guidelines on showing Stata data. Installing `groups` from the _Stata Journal_ website and showing the results of `groups cluster w_final goldstage1 locality` might be one way.  By the way, which regression produces the odds ratio you give?

Comment: Thank you I will check it out.
Odds ratio are from logistic regression.

Comment: No; for which logistic regression: villages or localities?

Comment: It's for the locality.